# Adding folder to custom DNN extension

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am creating a custom extension for DNN using [Christoc's DotNetNuke Module and Theme Development Template](https://christoctemplate.codeplex.com/)

I add folders to my extension project and i do a release build, once i install the extension on my site the folders are not there. These folders are part of the extension project. Do i need to add them as resource to the extension or something? because my *JavaScript* folder and *CSS* folder are there once installed and i created these folders manaully my self also

**Thank You**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the Folder, or the FILE TYPES in the folder to the BuildScripts within my project templates. Look at the ModulePackage.targets file.

Chris

Comment: I ended up adding to the `BuildScripts/ModulePAckage.targets` file. 

`<ItemGroup>     
   <InstallInclude Include="**\<folderName>\**" Exclude="packages\**" />
 </ItemGroup>` Thank you